# pip conf ignores my extra-index-url and times out even though pypi.org is in the config

Tags: python, pip

I have a local pypi server I use, and I configured my machine accordingly:

```
  [global]
  trusted-host = IP
  index-url = http://IP/simple
  extra-index-url = https://pypi.org/simple
```

This works well when I pip install:

```
$ pip install ipython pytest-html
Looking in indexes: http://IP/simple, https://pypi.org/simple
```

however, when I cut the connection to my local pypi server and expect it to try and install from pypi, nothing happens...

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2eb4252630>, 'Connection to IP timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ipython/
```

Why won't pip check in pypi before timing out?

I verified my pypi url is fine by installing like this:

```
    pip install ipython pytest-html --index-url https://pypi.org/simple
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.org/simple
Collecting ipython
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/2e/59cdacea6476a4c21b7c090a91250ffbcd085900f5eb9f4e4d68dd2ee4e3/ipython-7.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytest-html in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.22.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from ipython) (0.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from ipython) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from ipython) (42.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from ipython) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from ipython) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from ipython) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from ipython) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from ipython) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from ipython) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytest>=3.0 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest-html) (5.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytest-metadata in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest-html) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parso>=0.7.0 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython) (0.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pexpect; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest>=3.0->pytest-html) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest>=3.0->pytest-html) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest>=3.0->pytest-html) (20.4)
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.5.0 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest>=3.0->pytest-html) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2>=2.2.0; python_version < "3.6" in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest>=3.0->pytest-html) (2.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pluggy<1.0,>=0.12 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest>=3.0->pytest-html) (0.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools>=4.0.0 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pytest>=3.0->pytest-html) (8.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->pytest>=3.0->pytest-html) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in ./venv35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from packaging->pytest>=3.0->pytest-html) (2.4.7)
Installing collected packages: ipython
Successfully installed ipython-7.9.0
```

Comment: Once the max amount of retries is reached for your custom index, `pip` should continue looking for packages from PyPI.

Comment: How can I make it try both of them before retrying?

Comment: You can't, the indexes are tried one by one. You can decrease the amount of retries via `--retries=1` to speed up things, but that's it. Ideally, the custom index should be able to proxy requests for missing packages to PyPI, e.g. `devpi` can do that.